# Learning about SurfaceFlinger shared library

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, surfaceflinger

I want to develop a native android application which uses the SurfaceFlinger library from the Android-4.0.4
I want to learn about how the SurfaceFlinger library works in android, it's flow and also to build and run/debug it using the test data.
I want to understand the flow of SurfaceFlinger so that i can call the correct methods from my app.(cpp files).
I know that SurfaceFlinger API is not stable in android so i am specifically targeting my app to devices running on Android 4.0.4.

I also want to know which tools to be used to build and debug the shared library and procedure to carry it out.

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: @JiangYD i want to write a native application that invokes the methods from SurfaceFlinger code. So i want to learn about the flow of the SurfaceFlinger code and tools used to debug the code.

Comment: [link](http://zhan.renren.com/tag?value=surfaceflinger) [link](http://yangyou230.iteye.com/blog/1315347)

Comment: Thanks @JiangYD, can you please also tell me how can i compile and run and test the SurfaceFlinger code, and set up a debugger for it.

Answer (score 0):

Surface Flinger is an internal component on Android and is not designed to be programmable (hence the unstable API).

You best bet is to use OpenGL ES with an EGL windowed context. There in a nice example in the documentation of the [Native Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html).

Comment: i specifically want to work on SurfaceFlinger and not any other component, so any any help would be great.

Comment: In that case, download the Android source and read the code. It is the only resource you are going to find.

Comment: i have the downloaded code(not whole AOSP) with me but i cannot understand from where to start. I don't know how will i understand the flow of the code, please suggest any tools or specific procedure. Or how do i use the debugger for that purpose? and how do i test it's working?